# Shorhand for installing multiple npm modules from the same package

Tags: npm, npm-install

Any short hand for installing multiple npm modules from the same package ?

**I mean, instead of doing:**

`npm i @angular/common @angular/compiler @angular/core @angu
lar/forms @angular/http @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @angular/router @angular/router
-deprecated -S`

**Can I do something like:**

`npm i @angular/{common, compiler, core, forms, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router, router-deprecated} -S`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was much close to the solution in my question. I can do this by removing the extra space character from within curly braces like below:

`npm i @angular/{common,compiler,core,forms,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,router,router-deprecated} -S`

Comment: For the record, the curly braces syntax is a feature of the shell and thus only works on Macs and Linux environment. Aka doesn't work with Powershell on Windows.